# how to use comparison in php

Tags: php, arrays

i want to compare array $list_matkul which is from database to a string inside php

why my response "adalah" always showing false in my comparison

this is my code

```
<?php

require_once 'DB_Functions.php';
$response = array();
$db = new DB_Functions();

if (isset($_POST['no']) && isset($_POST['semester'])) {

    $no = $_POST['no'];
    $semester = $_POST['semester'];
    $list_matkul = array();
    $response['error'] = false;
    $sks = $db->getSks($no,$semester-1);
    $list_matkul = $db->getAllMatkulMhs($no,$semester);
    $response['matkul_list'] = array_values($list_matkul);

    for ($x = 0; $x < count($list_matkul); $x++) {
        if (array_values($list_matkul[$x]) == "matkul_1"){
        $response['adalah'] = true;
        $x+=999999;
        } else {
        $response['adalah'] = false;
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($response,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); 
}
?>
```

here is my json response

```
{
"error": false,
"matkul_list": [
{
"nama_matkul": "matkul_1"
},
{
"nama_matkul": "matkul_2"
},
{
"nama_matkul": "matkul_4"
},
{
"nama_matkul": "matkul_3"
}
],
"adalah": false
}
```

Comment: I noticed you're using POST arrays. If you're using a form for this and there is possible relevance, we need to see it. If it's irrelevant, please let me know  and I'll delete this comment.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner sorry i dont get what u mean , relevance with what ? could u explain ? , when iam trying to print response = array_values($list_matkul[$x]) there is "matkul_1" in it 
nevermind i've got the answer already

Comment: It's ok. I see you've gotten your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Without a Loop

Firstly, you can do this without using a loop at all.

```
//convert your array to a flat array of just names
$names = array_column($list_matkul, 'nama_matkul');

//set `adalah` value based on if the name was found in the array
$response['adalah'] = in_array('matkul_1', $names);

//echo json
echo json_encode($response,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

---

### With a Loop

If you insist on using a loop, in my opinion it would be easier to see what is going on if you use a `foreach` loop instead of a `for` loop. With a `for` loop, you need to keep up with the `$x` variable, but this isn't necessary in a `foreach` loop.

Also, you can get rid of your `else` statement by just ending the loop early.

```
//value defaults to false
$response['adalah'] = false;

//loop through all rows of array
foreach($list_matkul as $row) {

    //if name in array is "matkul_1"
    if($row['nama_matkul'] == 'matkul_1') {

        //set value to true if the above statement is true
        $response['adalah'] = true;

        //end loop, we know `adalah` is true, no need to loop anymore
        break;
    }
}
echo json_encode($response,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic seems wrong:

```
if (array_values($list_matkul[$x]) == "matkul_1"){
```

The function `array_values` returns an array and you are comparing it to a string. Maybe you meant to write

```
array_values($list_matkul)[$x] == "matkul_1"
```

Also, instead of `$x+=999999;` you could simply write `break;` ;)

---

Manual references:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php